# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, php

I update the security patches of Drupal 7. on changing view of one of my page i got this error (image attached). This error show only that particular page which affect the certain pages of website.i.e. https://www.smcin.com/content/product-category/standard-air-cylinders-32

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk9Wb.png)

[Error log page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6ito.png)

Comment: (Direct SQL errors to stackoverflow.com )

Answer (score 0):

I see `IN ()`.  That means you have an empty list, but failed to remove the associated part of the expression.

Comment: Even I found taht I have a module "IDS - Form alter " when I disable this module the HTTP error is removed but still the Items in my webpage not visible. And on enabling again got the above error. I didn't under how to resolve this IDS form alter error